# Как лучше сохранять данные

Tags: c#, xml, сервер

У меня в онлайн игре для каждого игрока есть способности. Которые на сервере сохраняются в базу данных. Этап сохранения выглядит так: всего, к примеру, 20 способностей. Открытых которых 12 нужно сохранить. 1 запрос в базу = сохранения 1 способность. И вот у меня 50 игроков уже зарегистрированно. А в базе почти ~600+ записей. Можно ли оптимизировать и делать сохранение в XML?

Comment: Покажите структуру БД

Comment: 600 записей и даже 600 000 записей для бд по сути ничто. Если вы обеспокоены хранением данных, то подумайте не о количестве записей, а о запросах в бд. Если вы раз в час по 12 записей извлекаете, то норм, а если вам для каждого раунда надо извлекать все 600 - тут может быть проблема

Comment: Ну вот 1 способность = запрос. Может лучше в xml сохранять?

Comment: 1 способность = 1 запрос - это не лучшая идея имхо. Если у вас 50 юзеров заходят в игру, то получается 50*20=1000 запросов. То есть количество запросов будет колв-во юзеров * колво сопсобностей на юзера. Это означает, что 5000 юзеров = 100 000 запросов. Это только чтение, не учитывая сохранения. Я бы сделал 1 запрос на все способности конкретного юзера, как для чтения, так и для записи. При чтении читать все способюности, при записи записывать только измененные способности. XML вообще тут никаким боком не поможет, для хранения данных используйте базы данных, не надо городить костыли.

Comment: Как написал  ```tym32167``` по каждому чиху не лучшая идея отправлять запрос, при загрузке игры шлите один запрос и получайте все способности разом, а если уже в процессе игры что то меняется, то это уже отдельная обработка. Я бы вместо xml предпочел хранить в json данные, удобно отправлять и принимать структуры.

Comment: По логике хранения данных когда их много где писалось что для пользователей лучше хранить данные пользователей локально, в облаке, сетевой папке. К примеру для пользователя создаете папку и там уже храните его файлы, файлы настроек, данные какие то. А в самой бд уже хранить инфу по типу id, логина, пароля может еще что то. И у бд есть ограничения по весу, то есть она не резиновая, лучше не забивать ее лишним если понимаете что ваш проект для большой аудитории

Comment: Какая у вас СУБД: реляционка или NoSql? Какая структура БД? / Да, во многих СУБД можно использовать XML/JSON/массивы/коллекции.

Comment: У меня каждая способность несет в себе информацию о том что за способность, его индекс. К кому он принадлежит, какой у него уровень. Сколько опыта в способности. И в каком слоте они скопированы. Как это все можно одним запросом сохранять? Когда нужны какие-то параметры по разному сохранять

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov MySQL 5.6